# How do I get the last day on the month using SQL Reporting Services

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SQL Server Reporting Services, how would I calculate the last day of the current month?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: Like buying a gun, there is a waiting period before you can accept your own answer.  I'll mark it as accepted in 2 days.

Comment: i like this approach!

Answer (score 26):

As it took me a while to Figure this out, and JC's answer was the simplest to modify and had a good logical structure. I expanded it Slightly for others searching for answers on this topic. 
I have found normally you don't just want the Last Day of a month / year you also want the first day of the month / year. So here they are the full lines to calculate just that. wtih the SQl version there also.

First Day of Current month

```
SSRS=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day)
SQL=SELECT DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0))
```

Last day of Current Month

```
SSRS=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
SQL=SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

First Day of Current year

```
SSRS=Today.AddMonths(1-Today.month).AddDays(1-Today.day)
SQL=SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
```

Last Day of Current Year

```
SSRS=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddMonths(13-today.month).AddDays(-1)
SQL=SELECT DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy,0,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())+1,0)))
```

I hope this helps somone.

Comment: Absolute best ever overview on what to do. Thanks @Technane

Answer (score 13):

I know you've found your own answer, but I'd suggest this alternative:

```
=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

It's a little easier to read, in my opinion, and might have slightly better performance (though most likely unnoticeable)

And, of course, if you wanted to pad out that date to 23:59:59, as is often necessary, just modify slightly:

```
=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the blog of a Microsoft SQL Team member:

```
-- returns the last day of the current month.
select dbo.Date(year(getdate()), month(getdate())+1,0)
```

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx

Hope this helps!
--Dubs

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for how to do this not as a SQL query but as an SSRS expression

Answer (score 0):

You may try this expression, Just replace now with your date field.

=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is an even easier way as in the marked answer:

`=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now())+1, 0)`

Since DateSerial() accepts integers as parameters one does not have to use AddMonths() and AddDays(). As in the example an instant calculation inside DateSerial() is possible.

Furthermore day 1 is the first day of the month while the first day minus one day is the last day of the month before (1-1=0). So the example will return the date of the last day of the current month.

Answer (score -2):

you can use an assembly for doing this work by adding it as a reference.

Comment: Perhaps a little more explanation would be inorder.