# SSRS - Find next Month End Date

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am looking to use an expression which will find the next month end date based on a month end date passed through by a parameter.

I am trying to convert the SQL statement I would use to do this into an SSRS expression.  The SQl statement I would use is:

DATEADD("m",  +1, @Mth_Start + 1) - 1

I would be grateful for any assistance in letting me know how the above can be converted into an SSRS expression.

Many thanks

Comment: So will your parameter always by the first of any given month? e.g. your parameter will be `01-Nov-2014` and you want your expression result to be `30-Nov-2014`?

Comment: If so, probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852874/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-on-the-month-using-sql-reporting-services

Comment: Hi Ian, No it will always be a month end date. Effectively if my parameter is 30-Nov-2014 I would like the expression to pull back 31-12-2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DateInterval and then . interval type with SSRS. Plus you cannot just add or minus to a date you need to use DateAdd so I have nested it as follows:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Parameters!Mth_Start.Value)))
```

Hope this helps, :-)