# RDLC-Report get last day of month from given date

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is there a way to get last date of month from given date in RDLC-report expression.I have a field 'toData' which have date e.g if its value is:
10-04-2017.It should show the last date of month which is 30-04-2017 in report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the last day on the month using SQL Reporting Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852874/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-on-the-month-using-sql-reporting-services)

Comment: I want to show last day of month of date having field 'toDate' not current's month.

Comment: Did you read the thread? It shows how to work it out for any given date, it's just that in the example they give it `Today` to get the current month, obviously you would use `toDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the Last Day of the month for a given date

`=DateSerial(Year(yourDateHere), Month(yourDateHere) + 1, 0)`

Formatting the date to dd-MM-yyyy 
like "01-01-2017"

`=FORMAT(DateSerial(Year(Fields!Date.Value), Month(Fields!Date.Value) + 1, 0), "dd-MM-yyyy")`