# SSRS concatenating parameters values to obtain date in the end

Tags: string, date, reporting-services, time, expression

hi guys i have the expression below which i am trying to use to concatenate some int param values and one int value.

In the end i want a date for the last day of the month based on what the user selected.

Spent all day on this, couldn't find anything in stack.

```
 =Parameters!Year.Value & 10 & IIF(LEN(Parameters!Period.Value) <= 1,0 & 
 Parameters!Period.Value,Parameters!Period.Value)
```

Comment: Is this what you need?

How do I get the last day on the month using SQL Reporting Services?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852874/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-on-the-month-using-sql-reporting-services

Comment: Give some example of the values you have an the expected result and it will be easier to help. I'm sure this is simple but without knowing more its hard to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that "Period" is the month, you are most likely looking for something like this:

```
=DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value, Parameters!Period.Value, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```